# Trouble positioning content in dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have this dropdown menu:

```
<nav>
           <ul>
               <li><a>Home</a></li>
               <li><a>Who are we</a></li>
               <li><a>Habitat</a></li>
               <li id="menu">
                   <a>Raising in Captivity</a>
                   <ul id="dropdown">
                    <li><a>Temperature and Humidity</a></li>
                    <li><a>UVB</a></li>
                    <li><a>Diet</a></li>
                </ul>
                </li>
           </ul>
       </nav>
```

and the CSS for it:

```
nav {
    border-top: solid 1px #DADADA;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #DADADA;
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;  
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#dropdown {
   display: none;
}

#dropdown.active {
     position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    line-height:15px; 
}

a {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and the JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click", openMenu);

function openMenu() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

When you click on the Raising in Captivity link it opens the three dropdown options and it works, but they are positioned inside the navigation, I want them to show up just below the Raising in Captivity element , outside of the bottom border, how can I do that with css?

Here is a demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/philip9/farc0xmz/1/

Comment: try [this](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)

Comment: You have a position:relative; overwriting the absolute on your #dropdown.active. Also the position:relative; should be on the parent of the dropdown. In this case the li. I would also add top:100%;left:0; to the #dropdown.active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#dropdown.active {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: absolute;
    line-height:20px; 
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
```

position: absolute. Then I think it looks nice with padding and margin-left added as well. Centers it under

Comment: @Philip youre welcome glad to help! you should mark as answered

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Still new to stack overflow and learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the style for `#dropdown.active`. There are 2 position styles, remove `position:releative` and add some margin to move the drop-down below the lower border.

```js
document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click", openMenu);

function openMenu() {
  document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("active");
}
```

```css
nav {
  border-top: solid 1px #DADADA;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #DADADA;
  margin-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#dropdown {
  display: none;
}

#dropdown.active {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 15px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

a {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<ul>
  <li><a>Home</a></li>
  <li><a>Who are we</a></li>
  <li><a>Habitat</a></li>
  <li id="menu">
    <a>Raising in Captivity</a>
    <ul id="dropdown">
      <li><a>Temperature and Humidity</a></li>
      <li><a>UVB</a></li>
      <li><a>Diet</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `position: relative` from `#dropdown.active` selector styles:

```
#dropdown.active {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    line-height:15px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is because you have both `position: absolute;` and `position: relative;` in the #dropdown.active CSS. Remove the `position: relative;` and adjust the margins.

Answer (score 0):

Added/Updated these styles

```
#dropdown a {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    #menu {
      position: relative;
    }

    #dropdown.active {
      position: absolute;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      line-height: 15px;
      left: 0;
      text-align: left;
    }
```

```css
nav {
  border-top: solid 1px #DADADA;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #DADADA;
  margin-top: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

#dropdown {
  display: none;
}

#menu {
  position: relative;
}

#dropdown.active {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  line-height: 15px;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


a {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#dropdown a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>Who are we</a></li>
    <li><a>Habitat</a></li>
    <li id="menu">
      <a>Raising in Captivity</a>
      <ul id="dropdown">
        <li><a>Temperature and Humidity</a></li>
        <li><a>UVB</a></li>
        <li><a>Diet</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<script>
  document.getElementById("menu").addEventListener("click", openMenu);

  function openMenu() {
    document.getElementById("dropdown").classList.toggle("active");
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS code contains a duplicate entry for position property. So remove *'position: relative'* from it. I added a *margin-top of 25px* to bring it below the bottom border.
You don't need to change the HTML and Javascript of your code. Change the CSS file as follows:

```
    nav {
        border-top: solid 1px #DADADA;
        border-bottom: solid 1px #DADADA;
        margin-top: 60px;
        text-align: center;  
    }

    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #dropdown {
        display: none;
    }

    #dropdown.active {
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 25px;
        line-height:15px; 
    }

    a {
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 10px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        color: black;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```